# Unable to implement MaxCLL, MaxFall, MasteringDisplayColorPrimaries parameter definitions using the MediaInfo.h library

Tags: c++, mediainfo

I can't implement the definition of the MaxCLL, MaxFall, MasteringDisplayColorPrimaries parameters using the MediaInfo.h library. Calling other parameters works fine.

I tried the following commands:

```
std::wstring maxCll = MI.Get(Stream_Video, 0, L"maximum_content_light_level");
std::wstring maxFall = MI.Get(Stream_Video, 0, L"maximum_frameaverage_light_level");
std::wstring mastering_display_color_primaries = MI.Get(Stream_Video, 0, L"mastering_display_color_primaries");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names are "MaxCLL", "MaxFALL", "MasteringDisplay_ColorPrimaries", "MasteringDisplay_Luminance".
Generally speaking, you can get the field names from e.g. the XML or JSON outputs or `mediainfo -f --Language=raw`.

Note: I also answered on the [MediaInfo forum topic](https://sourceforge.net/p/mediainfo/discussion/297610/thread/0c00966af7/).